# webview Facebook is deprecated Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I received a message from face book as the below one:

```
We have re-reviewed your Privacy Policy and it is now in compliance.

    However, as webview Facebook is deprecated, we will need you upgrade your version 8.2.0 or later of the Facebook SDK for Android.

    To avoid a disrupted user experience, please follow this documentation for your Facebook login to work again: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/deprecating-webviews

    Once successfully upgraded, do let us know and we will review your application in totality.
```

So while I am trying to login with facebook I found the below error:

```
I/System.out: onError
E/LoginActivity: SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1349195 [message]: The key hash does not match any stored key hashes. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android for more information.
```

Even after I updated the FB login package from:

```
    implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
```

to:

```
    implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-login:12.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
```

I found the same issue...

I hope someone could help me to solve this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says to open `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android` and follow the guide.
So I opened the link, and I think you need to check step 6: "Provide the Development and Release Key Hashes for Your App
[image]

Comment: thanks for you answer :), I tried to follow the steps it gives me the same error